# Angular 2 cli project -Socket.io not working

Tags: socket.io, angular2-cli

Folks, 
I have a angular 2 Cli project. Its a simple chatting application. But for some reasons, server is not receiving/sending message to client. There is no compile error and app works but no socket messaging.
Below is the code snippet from each:

Express:

```
 const express = require('express');
 const path = require('path');
 const http = require('http');
 const bodyParser = require('body-parser');


 const app = express();

 // Parsers for POST data
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

 // Point static path to dist
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));


  // Catch all other routes and return the index file
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
     res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
   });

 /**
  * Get port from environment and store in Express.
  */
  const port = process.env.PORT || '3000';
 app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */
 const server = http.createServer(app);

  //set socket.io for chat
   var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
  io.on('connnection', (socket) => {
  console.log('user connected');
  socket.on('message', (msg) => {
    console.log('Message Received: ', msg);
    socket.broadcast.emit('message', msg);
  });
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('user has disconnected');
  });


   });


     server.listen(port, () => console.log("server running"));
```

App component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as io from "socket.io-client";

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
 export class AppComponent {
  messages: Array<String>;
  chatBox: String;
  socket: any;
 constructor() {
  this.chatBox = "";
     this.socket = io("http://localhost:3000");
      this.socket.on("message", (msg) => {
        this.messages.push(msg);
      });
  }
  send(message) {
     this.socket.emit("message", message);
     this.chatBox = "";
  }

 }
```

Html:

```
  <ul>
   <li *ngFor="let item of messages">{{item}}</li>
  </ul>

 <input [(ngModel)]="chatBox" autocomplete="off" />
  <button (click)="send(chatBox)">Send</button>
```

I would appreciate any help or hint to resolve this.

If I simple express based server with html chatting works fine.

Thanks

Comment: any errors like failed to connect or something ?

Comment: One of my working code ..
https://gist.github.com/parthghiya/7a03cbf2bb5be5af7746e06a0d7d24fe

Comment: No error , just not getting any console.log message

Comment: i am talking about the front end /Angular 2 ...
Any errors in browser console ?
No console.logs because socket is not connected at all.

Comment: Nope, clean .. no errors at all.. neither on browsers  nor at server side. Is your project angular2 cli based?

Comment: Yes, My project is angular CLI based ..

Comment: Can u debug & Check the socket object .!

Comment: Is your project available on github? Can you share it pls? I'll debug it

Comment: I am afraid not :(  its not a public project

Comment: i debugged it, there is socket object and a field disconnected=true and connected=false; how to connect it? is there any other way or setting i need to look into?

Answer (score 0):

There's no code for connection to socket at all.

Change

this.socket = io("http://localhost:3000");

to

```
   this.socket=io.connect("http://localhost:3000")
```

Comment: not helping.... how did you read socket.io on client side? did you add script on angular-cli.json or put <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> in index.html or you put  <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script> in index.html